# sum of column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe with different datatypes in one column and i want the sum of this column. i tried to convert the column with df.apply(pd.to_numeric) but it wont work.

```
d = {'col1': ["1", 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_test["col1"].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

print(df_test["col1"].sum())
```

this should give me 3 but instead i get

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to assign the `col1` back to `df`:

```
In [1661]: df_test['col1'] = df_test["col1"].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

In [1662]: print(df_test["col1"].sum())
3
```